# Is watching route changes to capture user authenticated status redundant?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm going through [this tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/code/vue/okta_vue_sign-in_widget/#index-page) to setup Vue3 with Okta Auth.

I'm stuck at this code:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <nav>
      <div>
        <router-link to="/">
          Okta-Vue Sample Project
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/login" v-if="!authenticated">
          Login
        </router-link>
        <router-link to="/profile" v-if="authenticated" >
          Profile
        </router-link>
        <a v-if="authenticated" v-on:click="logout()">
          Logout
        </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="content">
      <router-view/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: function () {
    return { authenticated: false }
  },
  async created () {
    await this.isAuthenticated()
    this.$auth.authStateManager.subscribe(this.isAuthenticated)
  },
  watch: {
    // Everytime the route changes, check for auth status
    '$route': 'isAuthenticated'
  },
  methods: {
    async isAuthenticated () {
      this.authenticated = await this.$auth.isAuthenticated()
    },
    async logout () {
      await this.$auth.signOut()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
nav div a { margin-right: 10px }
</style>
```

I don't understand the need for monitoring route changes.

```
watch: {
    // Everytime the route changes, check for auth status
    '$route': 'isAuthenticated'
  },
```

And that's because we're already listening to state changes and updating the `authenticated` flag here:

```
this.$auth.authStateManager.subscribe(this.isAuthenticated)
```

My understanding is that `subscribe` will publish an event anytime the auth status of the user changes. Doesn't that make watching the route redundant?

Comment: use beforeRoute() on the router instance.

Comment: @Trent I’m thinking to not monitor route at all since I’m receiving events from subscribe. What do you think? Can you elaborate on your comment